# how to get document id in fire base for specific field value

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```js
exports.getref = (oid, successFunc, errFunc) => {
    dbconfig.collection('txn')
        .where('oid', '==', oid)
        .get()
        .then(docRef => {
            successFunc({
                id: docRef.id,
                success: true
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            errFunc({ id: null, success: false })
        })
```

here I want to get document id of my collection where field value oid equals oid  . how i can get doc id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform a query with Firestore, you get back a QuerySnapshot object, no matter how many documents match the query.

```
dbconfig.collection('txn')
    .where('oid', '==', oid)
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => { ... })
```

You have to use this [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) to find out what happened.  I suggest reading the linked API documentation for it.

You should check to see if it contains any documents at all with the [size](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#size) method, then if it has the document you're looking for, use the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs) array to find the DocumentSnapshot with the data.  That snapshot will have a DocumentReference property with the id:

```
if (querySnapshot.size == 1) {
    const snap = querySnapshot.docs[0];
    console.log(snap.ref.id);
}
else {
    console.log("query result in exactly one document");
}
```